# ios Parse.com - After enabling the local datastore PFFacebookUtils loginWithPermission block is never called

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

After enabling the (new) local datastore in Parse version 1.6.1 for iOS the block in PFFacebookUtils loginWithPermission gets never called.

```
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];
[Parse setApplicationId:@"***" clientKey:@"***"];
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
   // Gets never called
}];
```

When removing the [Parse enableLocalDatastore] the block gets called.

```
// [Parse enableLocalDatastore];
[Parse setApplicationId:@"***" clientKey:@"***"];
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
   // Gets called as in previous versions
}];
```

I also have the app switching methods to support Facebook Single Sign-On in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

I've checked the documentation and couldn't find any help. Did I miss something when enabling the local datastore?

Comment: This is a bug that has been submitted in different forms at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/custom/?tag_ids=475720899235524 and more specifically here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/704471719668983/. You may want to subscribe there, I am waiting for an answer from FB as well.

Comment: Oh, why are they so careless.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been fixed in Parse 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the local datastore is experiencing an exception.
Try to use

```
[[PFFacebookUtils loginWithPermissionsInBackground: perms] continueWithBlock: ^ id (BFTask * task) {
// breakpoint
}];
```

and inspect with lldb the task to see if task.exception is nil.

I'm having a similar problem: I can login to my app with the aforementioned method but then, if I logout, when I try lo log in again I am stuck and task.exception says:

> Attempted to change an objectId to one that's already known to the
>   OfflineStore.

Comment: `[PFFacebookUtils loginWithPermissionsInBackground: perms] continueWithBlock` seems to work for the login but after the first start I am getting a _warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread_ which is caused by an internal call of `[PFOfflineStore _initialzeTables]`.

Comment: I have some Parse internal calls on main thread too. I guess that at the moment this is the normal behavior of the API. After that call, does your app work as intended?

Comment: Using the      [PFFacebookUtils loginWithPermissionsInBackground: perms] continueWithBlock works fine and the block method is called. I also removed the call from the AppDelegate in the the ViewController didLoad method and the _warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread_ is now gone.

Comment: I was getting the same error, which I could only solve by not enabling the local datastore- http://stackoverflow.com/a/27805495/538993

Answer (score 0):

This could be related: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/994229510592686/
It is a bug and it will be fixed in the next Parse SDK release.