# PFLogInViewController error- unable to login to Facebook after logging out with Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, parse-platform

I am using PFLogInViewController to login to facebook which works successfully the first time-

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)controller
           didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
if([PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]){
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

        NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];
        NSString *name = userData[@"name"];
        NSString *location = userData[@"location"][@"name"];
        NSString *gender = userData[@"gender"];
        NSString *birthday = userData[@"birthday"];
        NSString *relationship = userData[@"relationship_status"];

        [user setObject:userData[@"id"] forKey:@"fbId"];
        [user setObject:userData[@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
        [user setObject:userData[@"email"] forKey:@"email"];
        [user saveInBackground];
        NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pictureURL];

        // Run network request asynchronously
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:
         ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
             if (connectionError == nil && data != nil) {
                 // Set the image in the header imageView
                 PFFile *profileImage=[PFFile fileWithData:data];
                 [user setObject:profileImage forKey:@"profileImage"];
                 [user saveInBackground];
             }
         }];

    }];
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

If I then call [PFUser logOut] and  open the PFLogInViewController again, when I tap the facebook icon to log in again, the facebook spinner spins indefinitely and I get the error "Attempted to change an objectId to one that's already known to the OfflineStore."

How do I log out of the current user and then login again using PFLogInViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove `[Parse enableLocalDatastore]` from the appDelegate, I no longer get this error.  If I am not pinning any objects is there any disadvantage to disabling this?  Will I still be able to use "saveEventually" if there is no network connection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to save same object(email) again.

On first login, that email id will be stored fisrt time. But, after logout, you are again trying to store same email.

Try to search that entry is already exists in Parse. If you want to update the other details of user then you can update that using objectId.

Comment: The `didLogInUser` delegate method is never called the second time.  The error occurs before it is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Try unlinking the PFUser from the PFFacebookUtils and also close the active Facebook session and clear it's token.

```
[[FBsession activeSession]closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I call `[PFFacebookUtils unlinkUser: [PFUser currentUser]];
        [[FBSession activeSession]closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        [PFUser logOut];`
But still get the same error.